# What is an interface's contract?

Tags: java, oop

I have seen many posts saying an interface is bounded by a contract which specifies the way in which it's methods should be implemented. But couldn't get what is meant by that. Could you please explain?

Comment: Just to make it very short: an interface is NOT bound by a contract: the interface IS the contract. The classes implementing the interface are bound by it.

Comment: gotcha. thanks @Stultuske

Comment: This is said because if a class implements an interface it must provide all¹ the classes specified in the interface or the code won't compile. (¹ Except where Java 8 has polluted interfaces with `default` methods).